# Elementary Linear Algebra problem w/ image.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

**Question:** The picture is the original in the $x_1,x_2$ plane, and the center of the circular face is at the origin. If we pick a matrix $A$ and set $y= Ax$, and draw the image of that figure in the $y_1,y_2$ plane, which matrix below draws which picture? Explain your answer.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

This is a question in my exam paper and has come up a few times in previous years. I haven't found anything related to it online. I think what's going on is that all of the images are various matrices and the matrices below correspond to inverses of the images. That's only my assumption and I have no idea how to answer it. Does anyone know what's going on or being asked?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For example, (b) is a "extending towards the line $\;y=-x\;$ (so to speak), and the only matrix that apparently does something close to that is the first one (for example, check the image of $\;(0,1)\;$ under that matrix: it is $\;(-2,1)\;$ , " to the left".

The second image is an extension south-north, so the $\;x\,-$ entries remain more or less the same, yet the $\;y\,-$ entries is mutliplied by a factor greater than $\;1\; = $  third matrix, and etc.

Try to do the other ones now.

Comment: Isn't (a) the original matrix. Centered at the origin?

Comment: @PatrickMoloney Put there (b). Don't stop because little things, like typos...

Comment: Thanks very much sorry I just didn't really understand the question. So the conclusion I've come up with is that the figure (d) is rotating the matrix anti-clockwise 90 degrees. This must mean that the 4th matrix relates to that transformation. And the figure (e) is ''extending towards the line $y=x$ and that means the second matrix is causing the extension to the right.

Comment: @PatrickMoloney Exactly${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$